# Find a sequence which converges to $(0,0)$ but whose function is a bounded non-convergent oscillating sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$ defined on $\left\{(x,y): y \neq 0\right\}$. Find a sequence $x^n=(x_n,y_n)$ which converges to $(0,0)$, but such that $f(x^n)$ is a bounded non-convergent oscillating sequence.

I tried mixing and matching various sequences for $x$ and $y$ such that they converge to $(0,0)$ but I unsure how to make it so that these same sequences allow $f(x^n)$ to be a bounded non-convergent oscillating sequence as requested. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know an example of a bounded non-convergent oscillating sequence in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $(-1)^n$ would work, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $(-1)^n$ is usually a good way to start. Something like $x_n = y_n\cdot (-1)^n$, with $y_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0^+$ should do the job.

**More:** (place your mouse over the gray area to reveal its contents)

> For instance, $x_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then $f(x_n,y_n) = (-1)^n$.